# Are flashpoints the quickest way to earn social points?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

The title pretty much says it all. Group questing really only seems to net me 10 - 15 social points a conversation. What's the best way to quickly level up my social points?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best way to quickly level social points is to repeatedly run the first flashpoint in the game (**The Black Talon/The Esseles**) with a group of four people. The conversation density is *incredibly* high here, and there are a large number of conversation options to earn Social Points from. Even better, if you significantly outlevel the instance, you can blast through the whole thing in a matter of minutes. This is also a *great* way to make large-scale alignment shifts should you need to for some reason late in the game.

As for how to get a group of four to do this? Just advertise in Fleet General that you'll happily run people through, or bring along three friends alts. You'll be doing them a huge favor getting them some easy XP and gear, and you'll rake in the social and LS/DS points.

Comment: This is good for the high level guy, but all the lvl 10-12 players in the group will only get about 2xp per kill. I did it yesterday. Not cool if you're lvl 10 and need xp.

Comment: The answer is about getting social points, not about XP.

Comment: yes, advertise in general or your guild that you want to run Esseles for social points, and declare everybody should skip all conversations with <space>. As long as someone is high enough level, like 30+, even boss battles last like 10 seconds tops.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran through Black Talon a few times with another player (we're both level 50). Took us around 20 minutes and gave us roughly 100 Social Points each, though it would obviously be more if we had 4 people. We also got 200 Light/Dark side points, which can be helpful if you're short on those as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 30+, you can just speeder past all the mobs to conversations and bosses and do runs in about 20 minutes if everyone is skipping the conversations.